# C# Method which takes another method as an argument regardless of input/return type

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm sorry if the title is unclear. Basically I want to DRY my code by moving a lot of repetitive error handling to one place.

I'm calling several methods, which all throw similar errors. Each takes different parameters, and returns different types. I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static ErrorWrapper<Void> Method1(string s1, string s2) {
        return Wrapper<Void>(System.Method1, s1, s2);
    }

    public static ErrorWrapper<string> Method2(string s) {
        return Wrapper<string>(System.Method2, s);
    }

    public static ErrorWrapper<MyOtherClass> Method3(string s, int i) {
        return Wrapper<MyOtherClass>(System.Method3, s, i)
    }

    private static ErrorWrapper<T> Wrapper<T>(Func f, /*parameters?*/) {
        try {
            return f(parameters);
        } catch {
            // Handle exceptions
        }
}
```

I need to do this because I'm writing bindings for a language without exception handling, so using a error wrapping class is the only way to call standard library methods safely.

Comment: Have you tried with `dynamic`?

Comment: What's `ErrorWrapper<Void>`? do you acutally have a type called `Void`?

Comment: @ATC Yes, I'm importing it from the native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something here -

```
private static ErrorWrapper<T> Wrapper<T>(Func<T> f) 
{
    // implementation
}
```

Usage:

```
return Wrapper<string>(() => System.Method2(s));

return Wrapper<MyOtherClass>(() => System.Method3(s, I));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion based on my understanding of what you are attempting. Unfortunately you must use a `DynamicInvoke` which is slow in order to check types at runtime when calling a general `Delegate`. You can't use `void` as a type argument to a generic, so I created a `MyVoid` class that I handle specially.

I updated my answer to reflect the `System.Method`s being actual methods, and not static fields, and so they must be cast when passed to `Wrapper<>` - C# has no way to convert a method to a general `Delegate`.

I have also added a type safe version but that requires creating a lot of boilerplate methods to handle the number of arguments, but it does eliminate a lot of casting and can call the delegate statically, which should be more efficient.

I accidentally had `Method3` take two string parameters initially, and the non-type-safe version didn't have an error until called at run time. The type-safe version caught the mistake at compile time.

```
public class MyVoid { }

public class ErrorWrapper<T> {
    public T Result;
    public bool ValidResult;
    public Exception Exception;

    public ErrorWrapper(T res) {
        ValidResult = true;
        Result = res;
    }

    public ErrorWrapper(Exception e) {
        Exception = e;
        ValidResult = false;
    }

    public ErrorWrapper() { //  void
        ValidResult = true;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static ErrorWrapper<MyVoid> Method1(string s1, string s2) => Wrapper<MyVoid>((Action<string, string>)System.Method1, s1, s2);
    public static ErrorWrapper<string> Method2(string s) => Wrapper<string>((Func<string, string>)System.Method2, s);
    public static ErrorWrapper<MyOtherClass> Method3(string s, int i) => Wrapper<MyOtherClass>((Func<string, int, MyOtherClass>)System.Method3, s, i);

    private static ErrorWrapper<T> Wrapper<T>(Delegate f, params object[] p) {
        try {
            switch (default(T)) {
                case MyVoid _:
                    f.DynamicInvoke(p);
                    return new ErrorWrapper<T>();
                default:
                    return new ErrorWrapper<T>((T)f.DynamicInvoke(p));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            return new ErrorWrapper<T>(e);
        }
    }
}

public static class ErrorWrapper {
    public static ErrorWrapper<T> New<T>(T res) => new ErrorWrapper<T>(res);
}

public class MyTypeSafeClass {
    public static ErrorWrapper<MyVoid> Method1(string s1, string s2) => WrapperAction(System.Method1, s1, s2);
    public static ErrorWrapper<string> Method2(string s) => WrapperFunc(System.Method2, s);
    public static ErrorWrapper<MyOtherClass> Method3(string s, int i) => WrapperFunc(System.Method3, s, i);

    private static ErrorWrapper<MyVoid> WrapperAction<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> f, T1 p1, T2 p2) {
        try {
            f(p1, p2);
            return ErrorWrapper.New(default(MyVoid));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            return new ErrorWrapper<MyVoid>(e);
        }
    }

    private static ErrorWrapper<TRes> WrapperFunc<T1, TRes>(Func<T1, TRes> f, T1 p1) {
        try {
            return ErrorWrapper.New(f(p1));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            return new ErrorWrapper<TRes>(e);
        }
    }

    private static ErrorWrapper<TRes> WrapperFunc<T1, T2, TRes>(Func<T1, T2, TRes> f, T1 p1, T2 p2) {
        try {
            return ErrorWrapper.New(f(p1, p2));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            return new ErrorWrapper<TRes>(e);
        }
    }
}
```